# AutoComplete in WinForms .NET PropertyGrid using UITypeEditor Dropdown

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, propertygrid

How can I get **AutoComplete** with WinForms .NET PropertyGrid while using a custom UITypeEditor Dropdown list?

I want users to type into the WinForms .NET PropertyGrid combobox edit field, and automatically select an item from my custom dropdown.

As you can see from the code snippet and screenshot below, I am using a derived UITypeEditor class to host a custom dropdown list in the PropertyGrid.

I want to somehow capture text from the PropertyGrid combobox TextChanged event, and use that to select an item in my custom dropdown. I assumed that the PropertyGrid does not naturally provide this functionality, and that I would have to employ some trickery to achieve it. It just don't know how.

My custom C# class:

```
class UIDropdownTypeEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    private IWindowsFormsEditorService _editorService = null;
    TypeConverter.StandardValuesCollection _list = null;

    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        // drop down mode
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown;
    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        _editorService = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));

        // Use a list box
        ListBox lb = new ListBox();
        more...
        more...

        // Show dropdown
        _editorService.DropDownControl(lb);
        return lb.SelectedItem;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you need to additionally implement the `TypeConverter` for this property and provide a list of standard values with the `TypeConverter.GetStandardValues` method. That way, when the user starts typing without opening the dropdown, the autocomplete will be available based on the provided standard values. But this does not allow you to get desired behaviour when the custom dropdown is opened, because this dropdown is somehow "modal" for the rest of the property grid

Comment: You have to find or buy or develop an autocomplete listbox (combobox, or special control), independently from the fact it's going to be used in property grid, and use it instead of the standard ListBox in the code you show. ie: the question is not specific to property grid.